# emit not being triggered within sweetalert once deployed

Tags: vue.js, sweetalert, vue-events, vue-sweetalert2

I'm using vue-sweetalert2 in my Vue project. When running it on my local machine the following works as expected, but once deployed on the live server the emit doesn't get triggered.

My code looks like this:

```
function tryEmit() {
  console.log('test');
  emit('test');
}

function myFunction() {
  tryEmit();

  Swal.fire(...).then((result) => {
    tryEmit();
  });
}
```

In the above code, the first tryEmit() works as expected both locally and live, the second one works correctly locally, but once deployed, it doesn't trigger the emit - although it does log `test` but nothing happens after that.

It's only when it's inside the `then` part that it doesn't work. I also tried it in the preConfirm and it didn't work there either. `myFunction` is also being called correctly (used logging to test this).

Both live and local use the same version of vue and sweetalert.

Comment: There might be an error in the promise so `tryEmit` is never invoked. Add a catch block and inspect if there any errors thrown: `Swal.fire(...).then((result) => { tryEmit() }).catch(e => console.log(e))`

Comment: No, definitely invokes tryEmit - I put a console.log there that is being logged.

Comment: When you call tryEmit in the promise you get the console.log?
Maybe share some more code

Comment: I updated the question a bit to show more of what I tried. Also can't figure out why it would work when testing but not when deployed. Thinking if the compilation might be causing the issue somehow (there are no build errors, but there is a warning about chunking - could that be related?)